# How to make File exist PHP work with For Each Loop?

Tags: php

I have made a function  to detect a file which work but when integrated with foreach the result becomes inaccurate

**accurate**

```
$urlpath = 'http://' .$domain.'/'.$txtfile;;

if (!file_exists($urlpath)) {
    echo 'The file ' . $txtfile . ' does not exist on ' .$domain. '<br/>';
}
```

Becomes inaccurate because of `foreach`:

```
foreach($domainlist as $domain) {

    $urlpath = 'http://' .$domain.'/'.$txtfile;;
    if (!file_exists($urlpath)) {
        echo 'The file ' . $txtfile . ' does not exist on ' .$domain. '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post detail of file_exists function ?

Comment: Is all the syntax errors in the $urlpath assignment due to sloppy typing here in stackoverflow? If thats a direct paste... then your problem lies there.

Comment: @KhánhBùiĐức `file_exists()` is http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: I think the author created a function with the same name (which is a bad idea! This overwrites the builtin function!)

Comment: I can't help you if you don't describe your problem. Post all relevant code, also the function you wrote. Also tell us what you expected to happen and what went wrong.

Comment: @Randall sorry fixed the code,I was testing up a static value the reason for the extra quote would still not work

Comment: @Aloso basically i am just wondering why foreach loop doesnt work

Comment: The foreach loop does work. Maybe your other code isn't working correctly. If you added more detail, I might be able to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

`file_exists()` would only work with a local path not URLs. You are trying to determine if the URL above is a file, use php `is_file()`

Answer (score 0):

`file_exists`() works in local/server files. If you want check via URL's you can for example verify response http code if is differ than `200` or it's `404`.

```
function url_file_exists($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_exec($ch);

    $exists = (!curl_errno($ch) && curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 200);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $exists;
}

if (!url_file_exists($urlpath)) { // $urlpath = http://www.example.com/file.txt
    echo 'File not exists.';
}
```